# Api Call works in Postman but in Java using OKHTTP (returns ec: 400)

Tags: java, okhttp

Code generated from postman:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\n    \"firstName\": \"Take on me\",\n    \"lastName\": \"Ill be gooooone\",\n    \"email\": \"blehblehbleh@email.com\",\n    \"ipAddress\": \"143.156.7.8\"\n}");
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api-sandbox.dwolla.com/customers")
                .post(body)
                .addHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.dwolla.v1.hal+json")
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer GRHGoQ7WAGy37SFWIpKnrNBAZ7TkJajeDoJlW9cq7X67pG2rvJ")
                .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .addHeader("Postman-Token", "f5966d7f-d8c6-4c23-868c-f5100223f8a0")
                .build();


        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: You should probably remove the token if its the real one

Comment: it is a token for the sandbox env that expires every 60 minutes

Comment: Maybe there is an error message in the response?